# How to get a value of another field having max in another field?

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is my table description. I want to get the value in StatusName where weight having maximum value. I want to select only the StatusName from this table.

```
status_weight
+------------+-------------+
| Field      | Type        |
+------------+-------------+
| id         | int(5)      |
| weight     | int(5)      |
| StatusName | varchar(25) |
+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select sw.*
from status_weight
order by weight desc
limit 1;
```

Note this returns one row with the maximum value.  If you want all possible duplicates, then you need a more complex query.  Something like:

```
select sw.*
from status_weight
where weight = (select max(weight) from status_weight);
```